# How to regenerate R.java after clean projet on eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm  working on android 2.3.3 , when I clean my project on eclipse the generated class R.java is deleted , I tried to fix the projects properties by a right click and choosing Android tools , but it does not works. 
How can I regenerate the R.java ? 

Thank you

Comment: take a look at the related questions on the right...

Comment: If it's all right with your resources the R.java will be recreated automatically. If it doesn't - means you have errors in resource files.

Comment: You need to rebuild the project, and this is either done automatically (Clean & Rebuild) or manually via the menu.

Comment: I imported my project again and R.java is generated , thank you

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse :
Select Help > check Updates...
Select the Installed Software tab.
Click Update...
If an update for ADT is available, select it and clickFinish.
Restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If there are any errors in the layout or any resource files there will be no build happening and the `R.java` file will not be created.

Please solve the errors and then try to clean the project.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you clean the project and it rebuilds, it imports

> import.android.R

so, delete this import and remove all errors from xml files. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you tried to speed up eclipse and unchecked
 **Preferences - > General -> Startup and Shutdown - > Android Development Toolkit**
 check it back and restart eclipse, then R will generate automatically