# R.java file gets deleted suddenly on cleaning project

Tags: java, android, xml

on cleaning a project to update a image My R.java file in gen folder got deleted with no clue how , as a result giving errors how to recover it

Comment: it is the standard process when you clean a project. If `R file` is not recovering you have errors somewhere in your code, fix them, then `R.java` will appear again

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430721/how-to-regenerate-r-java-after-clean-projet-on-eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete gen and bin folder. And perform build. 
If R.java file is not generated, probably you have some errors with resources.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Android manifest file. I bet you have a typo there. If manifest is clear, `R.java` will be automatically re-genrated.

Also remove all reference to the `R.java` file in your source that u might have imported mistakenly.

Answer (score 1):

Check your resource files. Remember that your file names must contain only [a-z0-9_.] No "-".

The best way to know where the problem is coming from is to check the "problems" view in eclipse.